# Products search on the website - GET in HTML script

Tags: joomla

I created an online store with a search bar and "search" button separately.
How can I associate the search with products available on the website and by the "search" button?

I would like the search to take place in html script.

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
</form>
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: You are using wordpress? I am unfamiliar with joomla... let me look at that... but WooCommerce, an ecommerce plugin for wordpress is a great go to for online stores. You can upload your product, set variables for each product, and it comes with a built in search for product feature... And much, much more. With wordpress, you kind of want to be careful as to not reinvent the wheel. There might be other plugins you can use and link with your code using hooks and filters.

Comment: I am using Joomla, create webiste in Gridbox Editor. I would like to searching.      
I would like products to be searched on the website through the html / php script.

Comment: Okay, I understand now... Joomla is a CMS, like wordpress. So you are using Joomla, not wordpress. So you are wanting to submit the form is your question? Have you looked into javascript to link the button to the form? Like a `<form id="myForm">......</form><button onclick='document.getElementById("myForm").submit();'>Search</button>`

Comment: Did this work / was it helpful?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work